# Determining the rank of a $4 \times 5$ matrix whos null space is three dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> What is the the rank of a $4 \times 5$ matrix whose null space is three dimensional?

Wouldn't this mean that I would have something like

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

So wouldn't it's rank = (the # of pivot columns) - the null space dimension? so **rank** $= 4 - 3 = 1$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: I've heard it @carmichael561 . Would that mean  that the $rank = $ (#ofPivotColumns) - (null space dimension) => 4 - 3 = 1?

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem says that given a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the rank of $T$ plus the dimension of its nullspace is equal to $n$. What are $n$ and $m$ for a $4\times 5$ matrix?

Comment: So then (1 + 3)? So its rank is 1!

Comment: Well, a $4\times 5$ matrix defines a map from $\mathbb{R}^5$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$. So rank plus nullity equals $5$.

Comment: Oh I see. **rank** of $A$ is just the dimension of the column space of $A$ so it's just $5$ because $A$ has $5$ columns correct?

Comment: Just because the column space is generated by five columns does **not** mean that these columns form a **basis** for the column space. Review the notion of "dimension".

Comment: The space $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n$. **Every** basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of $n$ vectors, so why do you say that @AlexProvost I'm confused.

Comment: I made a typo. the rank should be = $4$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is generated by $10000000$ vectors if you want, but its dimension is nonetheless $n$.

Comment: So in this case my rank would be $2$ then correct? @AlexProvost

Comment: Yes, total number of columns minus nullity.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. You're saying just because I have 5 columns , doesn't mean that I'm going to have a number in each column correct? So it could be different

Comment: I'm saying that, generally, the five columns won't be linearly independent, and so they won't form a basis. The pivots give you a linearly independent subset of columns that still generate the column space (i.e., a basis).

Comment: And by "review the notion of dimension", I meant: what is the dimension of a space in terms of spanning and linearly independent subsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank-nullity theorem states that for a matrix $A$ 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)+\DeclareMathOperator{nullity}{nullity}\nullity(A)=\#\text{ columns  of }A
$$
The rank of $A$ is the dimension of the column space of $A$ and $\nullity(A)$ is the dimension of the null space of $A$.

Your question asks for the rank of a $4\times 5$ matrix $A$ whose null space is three-dimensional. The rank-nullity theorem immediately implies
$$
\rank(A)=\#\text{ columns of }A-\nullity(A)=5-3=2
$$

The example you give is
$$
A = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
This matrix has $\rank(A)=4$ and thus $\nullity(A)=4-3=1$. It is thus not a relevant example of your problem.

A relevant example would be
$$
A = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
This matrix has nullity three and thus has rank two.

Comment: I am so confused. I thought the rank was the number of pivot columns as alex said below me. Also, how is a 4x5 matrix not a relevant example?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, there could be numbers in the 5th column.

Comment: I think a relevant example would be S = {[1,5,0,2,0],[0,1,2,3,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]}, where S is the set of row vectors of some matrix A.

Answer (score 1):

The number of pivot columns *is* the rank: row-reducing gives you pivots, which in turn gives you a basis for the column space. In terms of matrices, the rank-nullity theorem says that the *total* number of columns is equal to the sum of the nullity and the rank.

You seem to be confusing the total number of columns with the dimension of the column space. Take for example the $1 \times 2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Evidently the total number of columns is $2$, but these columns are linearly *dependent*. A basis for the column space consists of a single column $\begin{pmatrix}1 \end{pmatrix}$, and hence the rank = dimension of column space = $1$.